# how to display no.of elements having same data-id and class?

Tags: javascript

I am having total 15 elements, in which 13 elements have same data-`id="ankush"`, 14 element have same `class="ankush"` and 1 element have only `id="ankush"`. so i want to display total no. of elements which have data-id and class?

```html
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" id="ankush"></div>
```

Comment: ```var len = document.querySelectorAll('.ankush[data-id="ankush"]').length;
alert(len);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get list of elements according to given selectors. `.ankush[data-id="ankush"]` selector will return element with `ankush` class and `data-id` equal to `ankush`. You can get total length by using `length` property as below:

```js
document.getElementById('total').textContent = document.querySelectorAll('.ankush[data-id="ankush"]').length;
```

```html
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"  data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" id="ankush"></div>

<div>total: <span id="total">0</span></div>
```

Comment: Not recemended to use `.innerHTML` consider using `.text` OR `.textContent` - Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Also an answer should NOT be code only - Please add some explanation as well on how you got the results to help OP understand better.

Comment: You are right, but we are getting the length of matching elements and it returns number

Comment: From the MDN => Warning: If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated review process

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps?

In this case, as per your question, I am combining the logic for retrieving "ankush" from both, 'class' and 'data-id' such that you have total matching numbers.

```js
var matchingResult = 
document.querySelectorAll(' [data-id="ankush"]', '[class="ankush"] ');

console.log(matchingResult.length);
```

```html
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush"></div>
<div class="ankush" id="ankush"></div>
```

Comment: An Answer should NOT be code only - Please add some explanation as well on how you got the results and to help OP understand better.

Comment: No need to apogise :) just add some info how you have got the results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
// rootElement must be in format
//  `.someClassName *`
//   or `#someElementID *`
//   or `tagName *`
//
// NOTE: DONT REMOVE THE `*`

const rootElement = "#container *";

const count = [...document.querySelectorAll(rootElement)]
  .map(el => ({
    dataset: Object.assign({}, el.dataset),
    classList: el.classList.value.split(" ").filter(c => c.length)
  }))
  .reduce((acc, {
    dataset,
    classList
  }) => (
    Object.keys(dataset).forEach(ds => {
      acc.dataset[ds] = acc.dataset[ds] || {};
      acc.dataset[ds][dataset[ds]] = 1 + (acc.dataset[ds][dataset[ds]] || 0);
    }),
    classList.forEach(klass => {
      acc.classList[klass] = 1 + (acc.classList[klass] || 0)
    }),
    acc
  ), {
    dataset: {},
    classList: {}
  });

console.log(count);
```

```html
<main id="container">
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush2" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush2" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush1"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" data-id="ankush1"></div>
  <div class="test" data-test="pass"></div>
  <div data-test="pass"></div>
  <div data-test="pass"></div>
  <div class="ankush"></div>
  <div class="ankush" id="ankush"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. Read and question and review your answer. Please.